# Connecting to Mysql using Jhipster

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, jhipster, liquibase

I have generated an spring boot + angular application . imported entities with jdl. working properly with h2 . I am newbie and want to use mysql.I have configured datasource in application-dev.yml with following code.

```
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blogdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
    username: name
    password:pass
h2:
    console:
        enabled: false
     hikari:
            data-source-properties:
                cachePrepStmts: true
                prepStmtCacheSize: 250
                prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
                useServerPrepStmts: true
    jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    database: mysql
    show-sql: true
```

2) I have updated my pom configuration from h2 to mysql with following code.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blogdb</url>
                <defaultSchemaName>blogdb</defaultSchemaName>
                <username>name</username>
                <password>**</password>
                <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:pt.farol.destfinder.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect&amp;hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <logging>debug</logging>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <version>${javassist.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase-hibernate5.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

**PROBLEM** when i run my project i am getting following error .

```
    The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\..\..\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: C:\..\.\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\lib\snakeyaml-1.13.jar
22:58:49.740 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
22:58:49.751 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
22:58:49.751 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/G:/Java%20Projects/target/classes/]
22:58:52.636 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/G:/Java%20Projects/target/classes/]
```

**Edit** 
[git repository link](https://github.com/sayjavajava/beam)

***yo-rc.json file***

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.beam"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.10.2",
    "baseName": "beam",
    "packageName": "com.beam",
    "packageFolder": "com/beam",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "session",
    "hibernateCache": "ehcache",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "rememberMeKey": "801a22f60c33f866035c634e04c3b5b096fdedc6",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your .m2 folder is corrupted, you could try deleting it and re-run mvnw

Comment: but when i use h2 configurations instead of mysql it works properly . let me try again

Comment: command -> mvnw  "application failed to start" .

Comment: so any another trick ?

Comment: maven build with force update -u

Comment: @GaëlMarziouI I have generated new project but still facing same issue at starting

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I have deleted .m2 folder and re-run command , but still same issue persisting .

Comment: @aliakbarazizkhani I have updated mvn clean install -U . but issue did not resolved

Comment: @GaëlMarziou question has been edited .

Comment: @nailanaseem  im getting same errors i tried jhipster for first time, not sure about all configurations

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer but I needed more space than in comments.

I have generated an app using your .yo-rc.json file and jhipster 4.10.2, it works fine. I also have the Class-Path manifest warning but it's harmless and the application works.

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ beam ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\Gaël\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar referenced one or more files tha
t do not exist: C:\Users\Gaël\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\lib\snakeyaml-1.13.jar
22:15:34.613 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
22:15:34.617 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/,

2017-11-13 22:15:57.237  INFO 20472 --- [  restartedMain] com.beam.BeamApp                         :
----------------------------------------------------------
        Application 'beam' is running! Access URLs:
        Local:          http://localhost:8180
        External:       http://172.27.112.1:8180
        Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

**So, I guess you're not pasting the real error.
What exactly is the symptom?**

Comment: so should i re-install maven ? PS: i have pasted error that is shown in log.same as your log but my application failed to start :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a new jhipster application, and choose Mysql at the creation moment. It takes few minutes, and you can check and compare.

Comment: I have generated new project , but still facing same issue at start .

Answer (score 1):

Normally in application-dev.yml spacing is considered so in password to be

yours,
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blogdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
    username: name
    password:pass
what to be done is,

datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blogdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
    username: name
    password: pass

just check it out

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read over https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and edit your answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to install a JHipster project with Mysql, I had the same problem, My problem got resolved when I Change

```
datasource:
type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blogdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
username: name
password:pass
```

to

```
datasource:
type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blogdb /*Removed the parameters*/
username: name
password:pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error if you are using docker, so replace localhost to your docker IP

```
type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:3306/library
        username: root
```

Comment: Maybe more details? -- I'm from [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/22325970), not having same problem.